# Beginner: null pointer exception

Tags: java, netbeans

I just started with Java. I'm trying to make a simple (almost Hello world) program:

1. The user enters the name of three players
2. The program prints these three names
3. End

The player class is called "Jugador". I get a NullPointerException error. I more or less understand the concept, but I still have no idea why it isn't working =(. Any help is appreciated.

Source:

Chicago2.java:

```
package chicago2;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Chicago2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s;
        Jugador jugadores[];
        jugadores=new Jugador[3];
        int i=1;
        System.out.println("Loading players:");
        for(Jugador x: jugadores) {
            s=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name of player "+i+": ");
            x = new Jugador(s);
            System.out.println("Player "+i+": "+x.getName());
            i++;
        }

        System.out.println("Printing players name:");
        for(Jugador y : jugadores) {
                System.out.println("Plays: "+y.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Jugador.java:

```
package chicago2;
public class Jugador { 
    private String name;
    public Jugador(String nom)
    {
        name=nom;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    } 
}
```

Error I get
(Output):

> run:
>
> Loading players:
>
> Player 1: a
>
> Player 2: b
>
> Player 3: c
>
> Printing players name:
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at chicago2.Chicago2.main(Chicago2.java:19)
>
> Java Result: 1

Line 19 is:

```
System.out.println("Plays: "+y.getName());
```

Work environment:

> Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.3 (Build 201302132200)
>
> Java: 1.7.0_17; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 23.7-b01
>
> Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_17-b02
>
> System: Linux version 2.6.32-41-generic running on amd64; UTF-8; en_US (nb)

Screenshot:

[image]
If you read this far, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names you're getting from user are not being stored in your array. You need to do that this way:-

```
x = new Jugador(s);
jugadores[i] = x;
```

Also, the `int i=1;` should be `int i=0;`.

But for better readability, see the below code changes:-

```
System.out.println("Loading players:");
for(int i = 0; i < jugadores.length; i++) { // Better readability.
        s=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Name of player "+i+": ");
        Jugador x = new Jugador(s);
        jugadores[i] = x; // Added
        System.out.println("Player "+i+": "+x.getName());
}
```

Comment: Better still, change the `for(Jugador x: jugadores)` to `for (int i = 0; i < jugadores.length; ++i)`, etc... Iterating over an uninitialized array is very unusual.

Answer (score 0):

You are not really storing anything in `jugadores`.

To store, replace the line `x = new Jugador(s);` with `x = jugadores[i-1] =new Jugador(s);`